# ValueError: window size cannot be larger than the image

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror

I'm using openpiv to analyze two sets of video frames, and I'm getting the above error for a cell containing the following:

```
images_a = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_a, "frame_00*0.jpg"))
im_shape_a = plt.imread(images_a[0]).shape
a_set = np.zeros((im_shape_a[0], im_shape_a[1], len(images_a)))

images_b = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_b, "frame_00*0.jpg"))
im_shape_b = plt.imread(images_b[0]).shape
b_set = np.zeros((im_shape_b[0], im_shape_b[1], len(images_b)))

u, v, w, sig2noise = extended_search_area_piv3D(a_set, b_set,
                                                window_size=window_size,
                                                overlap=overlap,
                                                search_area_size=search_area,
                                                dt=(1 / du, 1 / dv, 1 / dw),
                                                subpixel_method='gaussian',
                                                sig2noise_method='peak2peak',
                                                width=2)
```

I've tried printing the values of the variables I think are causing the error, which returns:

```
window_size =  (49, 49, 11)
search_area_size =  (49, 49, 11)
image_dim =  (123.02, 123.02, 122.86)
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error, and how I might go about fixing it?